# Make .gitignore ignore everything except one file

Tags: git, gitignore

I'm pretty new with the whole .gitignore thing so I hope someone can help me out with this.

We're developing with Xamarin and we would like to ignore the packages/ folder except one file which is placed in different (sub)directories.

I would like to keep the following file:

```
/packages/SQLitePCL.raw_basic.0.8.2/build/Xamarin.iOS10/SQLitePCL.raw_basic.targets
```

But all the other folders and files inside /packages/ I would like to be removed.

I tried something like:

```
packages/
!packages/SQLitePCL.raw_basic.0.8.2/build/Xamarin.iOS10/SQLitePCL.raw_basic.targets
```

But I don't think this is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your `.gitignore` file is correct.

But I think that you have to remove `packages` in the remote before adding `packages` to your `.gitignore` file by command:

```
git rm --cached packages
git push origin master
```

And make sure that `.gitignore` is located same parent directory with `packages`

In the better way, I think you should create a `.gitignore` located in `packages` with the content:

```
*
!SQLitePCL.raw_basic.0.8.2/build/Xamarin.iOS10/SQLitePCL.raw_basic.targets
!.gitignore
```

Comment: git rm --cached packages gives me: fatal: pathspec 'packages' did not match any files

Comment: try the way push `.gitignore` file into `packages` directory

Comment: Did that too.. same problem occurs sadly