# How to use .gitignore to ignore everything in a directory except one file?

Tags: git, gitignore

I've found several purported solutions to this problem here on SO, but for some unknown reason none of them work for me.

I need to ignore everything in a given folder except for one particular file. Easy, right? Not so fast.

I've tried most every suggested answer for each of these questions:

- [Make .gitignore ignore everything except a few files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/987142)
- [Using .gitignore to ignore everything but specific directories](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5241644)
- [Make .gitignore ignore everything except one file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33520079)
- [.gitignore - Ignore everything in a directory except one file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36203525)
- [How to ignore everything in a directory except one file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39450654)
- [gitignore everything except specific files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22896230)

...but I'm no further along than when I started.

Here's the path to the file to include:

```
D:\Projects\Website\Website\bin\Settings.json
```

The repo is at:

```
D:\Projects\Website
```

My `.gitignore` file was generated by Visual Studio, so it contains this entry:

```
[Bb]in/
```

According to many of the answers to the questions above, I should be able to do something like this:

```
!/Website/[Bb]in/Settings.json
```

...but that doesn't work. The file is still ignored.

None of these permutations do the trick:

```
!*/Settings.json
!**/Settings.json
![Bb]in/Settings.json
![Bb]in/**/Settings.json
![Ww]ebsite/[Bb]in/Settings.json
!Website/bin/Settings.json
!/Website/bin/Settings.json
```

I've also tried putting a separate `.gitignore` file in `bin`:

```
# Don't block Settings.json
!Settings.json
!.gitignore
```

No luck.

How can I block everything in `[Bb]in` except for the `Settings.json` file?

- Expected result:
  `Website\bin\Settings.json` is not ignored
- Actual result:
  `Website\bin\Settings.json` continues to be ignored

Comment: Have you tried writing a simple file path without `[]` and `**`?

Comment: I did just now (`!Website/bin/Settings.json`), but still no success.

Comment: p.s. I've also verified that the file actually exists in `bin`.

Comment: And what exactly did you expect to happen as opposed to what actually happens?

Comment: Thanks, I've edited my question accordingly.

Comment: How did you determine that the file is still ignored?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236463/discussion-between-intexx-and-mkrieger1).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Adding on to [LeGEC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68945642/1256452), which is fine, I note that you commented:

> That works. It strikes me as a bit brittle (maybe that's just my imagination, and hopefully I'll be proven spectacularly wrong), but if this is the only way, I can live with it.

It's not the *only* way, and I have that same itchy feeling about it being brittle or otherwise somehow subtly wrong.  It *does* work and it won't break in normal everyday use, but it just seems wrong to me to have files that are, and stay, tracked solely because they are tracked in the commits you extract, as you go about making new commits.

The trick here is that the Git path name `Website/bin/Settings.json` results in a file that lives in a folder once extracted: the file `Settings.json` is in the folder `bin` (which in turn is in the folder `Website`, but that's just adding on to the pile; one "in-the-folder" layer is enough here).

Note that to Git, `Website/bin/Settings.json` is just a file name: that file name gets stored like that, with forward slashes, in Git's index (AKA staging area).<sup>1</sup>  The problem occurs *later*, when Git is scanning your *working tree*.  The exclusion handling that Git does—using `.git/info/exclude` and the various `.gitignore` files—works via working tree files.  It has to: it is all about *untracked files*, and the very definition of *untracked file* is *a file that exists in your working tree, but not in Git's index*.

When Git is comparing the current (`HEAD`) commit's content—the set of stored files in the current commit, with all of their data—to the files in the index / staging-area, Git does not have to, and does not, look at your *working tree* at all.  Everything Git needs is in the repository: the current commit is determined by reading `HEAD`, which resolves to a commit hash ID, which resolves to an internal tree object, which obtains for Git all the file names and modes and their hash IDs.  The proposed *next* commit, in the index / staging-area, contains the file names and modes and their hash IDs.  The hash IDs let Git know if files are 100% matches or not, and for most purposes that's all we care about: `git status` just prints an `M` for modified, or the word `modified`, without figuring out *what actually changed*, for instance.

Reading through the working tree, though: well, that's *way* harder.  The OS gets in the way here.  Sure, there may be a C library `scandir` or `readdir` function, or some other way to enumerate the contents of a folder.  But Git still has to call `lstat` on each name, perhaps.<sup>2</sup>  In any case, if you analyze timing results from why `git status` took more than 20 nanoseconds, you find that it spends a lot of time just reading directories.  Wouldn't it be nice if we could find some shortcut for this?

Enter `.gitignore` and other exclusion files: if we read the top level work-tree and find directories named `tmp` and `zorg`, but those *directories* are ignored—via `*` or `*/` or `tmp` or `tmp/` or whatever—why, then, we don't even have to open and read them at all!  It won't matter whether `./tmp` contains one file, or one billion files: we'll skip the whole thing!  Given that just opening and reading a directory to find its file names can take milliseconds—and using `lstat` on each name can add many more—this is a huge savings.

So, Git does this.  If Git is preparing a working-tree walk, and it is *allowed* to skip looking inside some folder / directory, it *does* skip looking inside that folder.  Hence, if your `.gitignore` file says:

```
*
```

then any directory name will match, and Git will skip opening, much less reading, the directory.  This happens to your `Website` folder.

If your `.gitignore` reads:

```
*
!Website
```

though, when Git reads the top level directory and finds the name `Website`, it *can't* ignore that.  So Git opens the `Website` folder and finds `bin`, among other things.  But: `bin` does match `*` and does not match `Website`, so it's ignore-able.  That means Git can skip right over it, never looking inside it.  You'll need to add `Website/bin`:

```
*
!Website
!Website/bin
```

Now Git has to open `Website/bin` and read it.  Every file and directory within it can be ignored, so to get `Settings.json` within it to be *not*-ignored, we need to list that file:

```
*
!Website
!Website/bin
!Website/bin/Settings.json
```

This fairly-minimal `.gitignore` file will work.  It does, however, have one flaw.  If there's a file or directory in `bin` named `Website`, that file or directory will be not-ignored.  If not-ignored, Git will complain about it being untracked, or add it with `git add .`, or other undesirable behaviors.  To fix that, we should make sure that only `Website` is matched, not, e.g., `bin/Website`.  This gets us to the *second* tricky part of Git's exclusion rules.

---

<sup>1</sup>The format for index entries is a bit messy and gets compressed, depending on index format version (of which there are several), but `git ls-files --stage` will dump out the main stuff of interest, and there, you'll see the file named with embedded forward slashes.  Git is, of course, capable of handling, and understanding, the backward slashes that Windows uses here, and hence stores the file in the `bin` folder in the `Website` directory.

Strings in Git's index are case-sensitive and are stored as UTF-8 or equivalent, regardless of how the file names are stored in the file system, and regardless of whether the file system's file names are case-insensitive.

<sup>2</sup>Some `readdir` variants include a type field, DT_DIR for instance, that—if you can rely on it—let you skip this step sometimes; that can be a huge time-saver.  I don't know if Git tries to do this: the working tree code has been revised multiple times, and now has all the complications from the fsmonitor code, which is a different way to speed things up, so I have not looked lately.

---

#### The other tricky part: anchored vs un-anchored names

To understand this part properly, I like to borrow a concept from regular expressions: the idea of *anchoring* something to the left or right.  In a regular expression like `me*s`, we'll match `ms pacman` and `message`, but not `memory`, because we're looking for `m`, then any number of `e`s, then `s`, and `memory` has no `s`.  But we'll also match `acmestorage` because that has `m` followed by one `e` followed by `s`, embedded within `acme` and `storage` (which run together).  We can avoid some of this by *anchoring* the match at the left: `^m*s` won't match `acmestorage` because the `m` has to be the *first* letter.

(REs also let us anchor at the right with `$`, typically.  Each RE syntax has its own peculiarities, and `.gitignore` files use glob syntax rather than RE syntax, so let's not get too far down this rabbit hole.  Just remember the idea of anchoring: sticking a match to the left or right, or both.  In Git's case, an anchored path is an exact match, stuck at both sides.  That's because the *right* side is *always* anchored.  You'd have to use `path/*` or `path/**` to allow arbitrary right-hand-side parts.)

In our case, with `.gitignore`, we'd like to make sure that `Website` only matches at the *top level*, where we put the `.gitignore` file.  To do that, we can start the entry with a leading slash:

```
*
!/Website
!Website/bin
!Website/bin/Settings.json
```

Now `bin/Website` won't match the second line: the second line is anchored at the top (root) directory of the scan, and `bin/Website` is not at that level: it's one level down.

You might think we should do that for all three file names:

```
*
!/Website
!/Website/bin
!/Website/bin/Settings.json
```

This works, but it's not *necessary*, and the reason is that a `.gitignore` entry is *automatically* anchored if it has an *embedded* slash in it.  `Website/bin` has a slash in it that is not at either end, so it's automatically anchored.  `Website/bin/Settings.json` has two such slashes and is also anchored.

#### More tricky parts

I implied there were only two tricky parts here.  I lied.   There's one more way that exclusion files uses slashes, which is unfortunately tricky, and that is that a *final* slash makes an entry match *only* a directory name.  That is:

```
bin/
```

matches the `bin` directory but not a file named `bin`.

This rule is independent of the remaining rules:

- A leading `!` negates the whole thing, so that `!/Website/` means *don't ignore*.
- A leading `/` (after any leading `!`) or any embedded slash that's *not at the end* means "anchored, so that `!/Website/` is anchored.
- A trailing `/` means *only when it is a directory*, so `!/Website/` only matches a directory.  The trailing slash doesn't count for anchoring purposes (and you should never use a double trailing slash) so if you want anchoring, be sure to include a leading or embedded slash.

Using *all* of these rules, we come up with:

```
*
!/Website
!Website/bin
!Website/bin/Settings.json
```

which is complete and correct (provided I have the right upper and lower case here: remember that *Git* will be case-sensitive, regardless of your file system).  But there's one other trick we can use that gives us a slightly shorter file.  Suppose we write:

```
*
!*/
!Website/bin/Settings.json
```

Git will:

- open and read the top level working tree directory;
- for each *file*, ignore it (`*`);
- for each *directory*, *not* ignore it (`!*/`);
- find the `Website` directory, hence open and read it;
- for each file in `Website/`, ignore it (`*`);
- find the directory `bin` and *not* ignore it (`!*/`);
- open and read the `Website/bin` directory;
- find each file and ignore it (`*`) *except* for `Website/bin/Settings.json`.

The downside to this three-line version is that, during the above processing, Git will open and read *every* directory, including every subdirectory of every directory, so if there is a top-level `tmp` directory containing one billion files (directly or after recursing), Git will spend time checking every single one of them.  That is, `!*/` completely defeats the "don't bother looking here" optimization that saves so much time in some cases.

What would be nice is if Git's exclusion code were smart enough to realize that if you write:

```
*
!Website/bin/Settings.json
```

it should *automatically* register `!/Website/` and `!/Website/bin/` into its exclusion list if those aren't already present.  This seems pretty straightforward to do.  (Precisely how to do the negation and anchoring depends on the internal data structures here, which I have not looked at in more than ten years...)

Comment: This is pretty interesting. I was able to get it to work using your suggested entries: `*~!Website~!Website/bin~!Website/bin/Settings.json` (where ~ represents a line break/feed). The `*` entry makes the difference. But something caught my eye: given the `!Website/bin` entry, why doesn't Git then include every other file in `Website/bin/*`? Don't misunderstand—I'm glad it doesn't. That's my desired effect. I'm just wondering why. (Maybe you've already answered this and I'm just missing it.)

Comment: The `!Website/bin` makes Git scan `Website/bin/` (and include a *file* named `Website/bin`, if one exists, which would mean `Website/bin` wouldn't be a directory and hence would not be scanned). So Git does *see* each file *in* `Website/bin`. But the file's name, in `Website/bin`, is, e.g., `Website/bin/a` (for file `a`), which doesn't match `Website/bin`: `Website/bin` is an anchored path and cannot match either `a/Website/bin` or `Website/bin/a`.

Comment: That leaves `Website/bin/a` to be matched only by the `*` rule, which is a positive (do-ignore) rule, which leaves the file ignored. It's ... complicated and kind of messy, but it really all does work. Also I realized my side remark about REs using separate `^` and `$` anchors is misleading here, so I added a sentence.

Comment: Whew! That's definitely a trip 'round Robin Hood's barn. FWIW, for safety I included your four-line block at the very end of the existing `.gitignore` (Visual Studio generated) rules. Thanks for the excellent writeup—it really helps a lot. I've changed my accepted answer to yours.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `git add -f` to instruct git to "override" ignore rules and track an individual file :

```
git add -f Website\bin\Settings.json
```

This file will stay tracked even if it matches an ignore pattern ; you would need to run `git rm --cached` to tell git to stop tracking this file.

Comment: That works. It strikes me as a bit brittle (maybe that's just my imagination, and hopefully I'll be proven spectacularly wrong), but if this is the only way, I can live with it. Thanks, you rescued my workday from certain doom.

Comment: I hope you don't mind too much... I changed my accepted answer to @torek's novella. With it I'm able to accomplish my original goal while staying within `.gitignore`. If something ends up going wrong there, I'll fall back to this solution.

Comment: no worry. I first started re-reading the docs for `gitignore`, and ended up thinking "wait, there is a shorter way" ;) kudos to torek for taking the time to give a detailed guide to navigate through ignore rules.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it :-)

Comment: Honestly this is better than reading essays about and spending inordinate amounts of time learning how to "properly" write a gitignore file to accommodate edge cases, for the nth time in one's career. Life is too short to deal with frankly *bad* software design when one can simply use --force.